# SQL Agrupar SUM por idempleado

Tags: mysql, select, sql, group-by

buenas e intentado de diferentes formas tratar de agrupar una suma de 3 tablas
escribire el ejemplo para ser mas claro

[image: tabla relacionada]

```
SELECT
    v.fecha_ven,
    e.apellidopaterno_emp,
    e.nombre_emp,
    SUM(d.precio_dv * d.cantidad_dv) AS Total
FROM
    detalleventa d
INNER JOIN venta v ON
    d.idventa = v.idventa
INNER JOIN empleado e ON
    v.idempleado = e.idempleado
GROUP BY
    e.idempleado
HAVING
    DATE_FORMAT(v.fecha_ven, '%m-%Y') = '12-2018'
```

y el resultado seria este

[image: consulta]

pero ese resultado solo me aparece cuando todos los registros se encuentran un mes, al añadir mas registros en otro mes ocurre esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven desaparece el otro Empleado
para dejar claro lo que hice fue cambiar de fecha 2 registros(idventa 4 y 5) del otro empleado ya existentes un mes atras

[image: cambios en registros]

esto ocaciona que la suma total de los 3 registros se muestre en el mes 11

y lo que intento es que sume los registros de acuerdo a su fecha

agradeceria su ayuda gracias :D

Comment: Porqué utilizas el HAVING en vez de un WHERE?

Comment: por que estoy usando una funcion de grupo que es SUM (tambien pueden ser (AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN) y si lo intento con where genera un error por que este solo opera sobre registros individuales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El empleado desaparece porque estas obteniendo el siguiente resultado (antes del `HAVING`):

```
fecha_ven   apellidopaterno     Total
2018-12-25  reymundo            1305
2018-11-15  lopez               119
```

Esto se da porque al agrupar únicamente por empleado, tenemos el problema de que hay mas de un mes para un mismo empleado, y el motor elige en este caso el primero, que es 11. Y luego, al aplicarle la cláusula `HAVING DATE_FORMAT(v.fecha_ven, '%m-%Y') = '12-2018'` indicas que solo deseas el mes 12 por lo que descartas el resultado del mes 11.

Vamos a trabajar con una versión resumida de tus tablas y con datos similares a los proporcionados:

```
create table venta(
    idventa int,
    idempleado int,
    cliente_ven varchar(45),
    fecha_ven date
);

create table empleado(
    idempleado int,
    apellidopaterno varchar(20)
);

create table detalleventa(
    iddetalleventa  int,
    idventa int,
    cantidad_dv    int,
    precio_dv   decimal(15,2)
);


insert into empleado values (1,'reymundo');
insert into empleado values (2,'lopez');

insert into venta values (4,2,'juan', '2018/11/15');
insert into venta values (5,2,'maria', '2018/11/22');
insert into venta values (6,1,'muro', '2018/12/25');
insert into venta values (7,2,'miro', '2018/12/11');
insert into venta values (8,1,'mir', '2018/12/14');
insert into venta values (9,1,'iii', '2018/12/16');
insert into venta values (10,1,'asd', '2018/12/18');

insert into detalleventa values (4, 4, 2, 2.0);
insert into detalleventa values (5, 5, 1, 15.0);
insert into detalleventa values (6, 6, 3, 10.0);
insert into detalleventa values (7, 7, 2, 50.0);
insert into detalleventa values (8, 8, 1, 100.0);
insert into detalleventa values (9, 9, 5, 200.0);
insert into detalleventa values (10, 10, 7, 25.0);
```

Ahora, el detalle es agrupar las ventas de cada empleado, por mes y por año, ya que si solo agrupamos por mes, cuando hayan ventas del 2019 o de años anteriores, sumara por mes independientemente del año. Podemos utilizar las funciones de `MONTH` y `YEAR` de MySql:

```
select idempleado, MONTH(fecha_ven) mes, YEAR(fecha_ven) año
from venta
group by idempleado, mes, año

idempleado  mes     año
1           12     2018
2           11     2018
2           12     2018
```

Y podemos ver que tenemos agrupados los empleados por mes y año. Ahora, agregamos el total del detalle de las venta para cada mes y año de cada empleado:

```
select idempleado, MONTH(fecha_ven) mes, YEAR(fecha_ven) año, SUM(d.cantidad_dv * precio_dv) as total
from venta v INNER JOIN detalleventa d
ON v.idventa = d.idventa
group by idempleado, mes, año
```

Los resultados son:

```
idempleado  mes     año     total
1           12     2018     1305
2           11     2018     19
2           12     2018     100
```

Podemos comprobar que efectivamente son correctos. Ahora agregamos la tabla de empleado para obtener el apellido:

```
select e.apellidopaterno, v.idempleado, MONTH(fecha_ven) mes, YEAR(fecha_ven) año, SUM(d.cantidad_dv * precio_dv) as total
from venta v INNER JOIN detalleventa d
ON v.idventa = d.idventa
INNER JOIN empleado e
ON v.idempleado = e.idempleado
group by v.idempleado, mes, año
```

Y obtenemos el resultado deseado:

```
apellidopaterno     idempleado  mes     año     total
reymundo                  1     12     2018     1305
lopez                     2     11     2018     19
lopez                     2     12     2018     100
```

Puedes revisar las consultas y datos en [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f2055/21).